# Running multiple junit testsuite in certain order using maven command

Tags: java, maven, junit, continuous-integration

I want to execute multiple `junit` testsuite in certain order using maven command.
I have the testsuite name as below,

1. JunitXXXTestSuite
2. JuitYYYTestSuite
3. JunitZZZTestSuite

These testsuites are executed with the below maven command,

```
mvn -Dtest=JunitXXXTestSuite,JunitZZZTestSuite,JunitYYYTestSuite test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

I want the testsuites to be executed in the given order as

1. JunitXXXTestSuite
2. JunitZZZTestSuite
3. JunitYYYTestSuite

With the above `maven` command, the testsuites are executed in random order everytime. Is there any way to mention the order of the testsuite execution?

Comment: Why do you want these testsuites to be executed in a specific order ? Do they depend on each other ?  
If it is the case, you should try to rewrite them so that the respect the FIRST principles : http://agileinaflash.blogspot.de/2009/02/first.html  
You'll gain a lot in maintenance

Comment: Yes.. There is some dependency with other projects and it should be executed in this specific order only

Comment: these test suite are executing the junit test cases for REST API and we are saving some values dynamically in system property and those values are used in other projects. So there is lot of dependencies in each project.

Comment: Then you should really try to make the testsuites independent. This can be obtained by creating some initialization scripts on each test suite that place the environment (DB, FileSystem, and your system properties...) in a given state.  

If you need help on that and do not find any answer in the web, please post a new question (and notify me with a comment here)

Comment: I will give a try. Thanks for the suggestion @Benoit

Comment: In the logic unit tests should not enforce an execution order and JUnit was not the basis for doing so, even if we can use the annotation:
FixMethodOrder ( MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING )
by against the testes of integration is with an order and for this it is best to use TestNG that offers more opportunity to model the order of executions

Answer (score 0):

Create Another Suite (Say Parent suite ) and mentioned your 3 suites over there and then run your parent suite.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Parent" preserver-order="true">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="JunitXXXTestSuite.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="JunitZZZTestSuite.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="JunitYYYTestSuite.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

and your maven Command as follows,

```
mvn -Dtest=Parent test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

Comment: Thanks mohan. But i was using Junit framework and not testNG. I have created a separate parent suite and mentioned the order of other test suite in it and it is working as expected. `@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
 com.test.commons.JunitXXXTestSuite.class,
 com.test.commons.JunitZZZTestSuite.class,
 com.test.commons.JunitYYYTestSuite.class
})

public class JunitParentSuite
{}` .

Comment: But the problem is that i cannot hard code the suite name in parent test suite. I am running the junit from jenkins using maven command. Sometime i need to run only one test suite. if i follow this approach i need to make the changes in parent suite and commit it in svn. Specifying the necessary test suite name in maven command look like the best solution for me but that is not executing the test suite in the specific order :(

Comment: Why dont you create another job?

Comment: Each test suite is dependent.

Comment: by intercepting what i understood is create four jobs with below maven commands, [Correct if  i wrong]

1. mvn -Dtest=Parent test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
2. mvn -Dtest=JunitXXXTestSuite -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
3. mvn -Dtest=JunitZZZTestSuite -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
4. mvn -Dtest=JunitYYYTestSuite test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

If you want to give over all run, trigger Job1, if you want to run only specfic suite run specific job

Comment: these test suite are executing the junit test cases for REST API and we are saving some values dynamically in system property and those values are used in other test suite. So there is lot of dependencies in each test suite. If i run it in different job each will run in separate JVM and i will not be able to get those dynamic values for system properties